# Backtracking and chess

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, chess

There's a chess field N*N where some black figures are already presented. Find the minimum of white queens that you need to put in the field so they can beat all black figures. Using backtrack-algorithm.

Firstly, I put all the possible queens to the positions where they can beat at least something. How then I should decide if the queen goes to the final solution or not?

Comment: Is my 1 step correct actually?

Comment: First start with one queen, and look if you can place that queen to attack all black figures. If that is impossible repeat the same with two queens, etc. This is an iterative deepening search algorithm.

Comment: Try to implementing something like this; Find all locations where a queen can capture something that hasn't already been captured, try to rank them so that locations which would capture the most other pieces comes first. Then place a queen at the first location. If this captures the last piece, check if the current solution is better than the one you previously got (or is the first one). Then, if more pieces are left to capture, apply the algorithm recursively. If you try to place more queens on the board than the best solution so far, simply return since it cannot be better.

Comment: When coming back to a recursive level, remove the queen you placed at that level, "uncapture" all the pieces it captured, the move on to the next possible location. You should also have some logic that makes sure you don't try the same combinations more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recursive pseudocode:

```
minQueensNeeded = ∞
procedure placeQueens():
  if all black pieces are under attack:
    minQueensNeeded = min(minQueensNeeded, number of queens on the board)
  else:
    for each black piece B that is not under attack:
      for each square S from which B can be captured:
        place a queen at S
        placeQueens()
        remove the queen at S
```

Note that it will visit the same situation more than once, because the queens can be placed in arbitrary order. This doesn't affect the answer, but it's not great for performance. You can fix it by only placing new queens on squares that come after the last queen in reading order.